# Laravel 4: making a combination of values/columns unique

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm importing a bunch of csv entries in my database with Laravel 4.

I can't really point at one column that has to be unique, it's a combination of 5 columns that makes it unique. However: how does one define this in Laravel?

**Option 1: schema builder**
You can use the $table->unique('email') method, but that only seems to allow one column, not a combination of columns.

**Option 2: Validation**
Less preferable, but I could validate the model before inserting it. However, again, using 'unique:[table]' validation rules, it will return an error when just one of the column values isn't unique, not a combination of them.

Can anyone tell me how I should go about this?
I'm sure I'm missing something, but I could use a push in the right direction :-)

Thanks,

Dieter

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can combine:

```
$table->unique( array('email','name') );
```

And pretty much everything in Laravel will accept arrays to do whatever you need to with 'more than one'.

Comment: But how to validate composite unique keys, i meant the second part using laravel validation. I couldn't understand the example from the laravel website?

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan Yes i think i also have the same [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683762/how-to-add-combined-unique-fields-validator-rule-in-laravel-4)

Comment: Laravel 5.4 is using the same syntax.

Answer (score 9):

Use Schema Builder's `unique()` method to define your data model, as Antonio mentioned.

Additionally, if you want to use validation on your model, consider my custom `Validator` rule for multiple `UNIQUE` indexes: https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

Comment: Thanks for the custom validator rule! Will be using that on top of the DB constraint, seems wrong to rely on a DB exception for the flow of the program.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this;

`$table->unique(["column1", "column2"], 'uq_columns');`

Which means that you will have a unique column combination of all the columns i.e. column1 and column2

Comment: I think that this is the correct answer. The original post was asking for a scenario whereby 2 columns must be unique *as a combination*. Therefore a single key is defined with both as described here. Thanks, I was also looking for this.

Comment: @GaryPaluk, you are wrong. This answer is about, `unique as a combination`, the last parameter is an index name.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is for Laravel 4, but I just came across this on searches and found a solution for Laravel >= 5.3

Here it is:

Of course, the migration may look something like

```
$table->unique( array('email','name') );
```

Then to validate this, you do not need to use custom rules, just advanced rules:

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('name', $request->name);
}),
```

Of course, you may want to validate name before of this. The name should be required so that you may finish with something like this:

```
'name' => 'required|max:255',
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('name', $request->name);
}),
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -4):

You can try this

```
$table->string("name");
$table->string("email")->unique("name")
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why would this make email and name unique as a pair?