# Laravel - Eloquent Relationship hasMany but also hasOne?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6.2

I've been all over the web and struggling with this for around 2 hours.

I have a USER model, a RUN model and a TIME model.

In the real world the user is in a race and gets their time entered in the database along with a USER_id and a RUN_id.

A user should only be able to have one row in the TIMES table for each RUN_id - if that makes sense!

Is this something I need to manage at the controller level? Or is there a relationship I can setup to ensure that a duplicate entry of this style can not enter the database?

Database structure at present:

---

USERS:

**name**

---

RUNS:

**name**

---

TIMES:

**time**

**user_id**

**run_id**

---

The Models:

USER:

```
public function times()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Time::class);
}
```

RUN:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Run extends Model
{    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function times()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Time::class);
    }
}
```

TIME:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Time extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Run::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the group relationship on the user model?

Comment: the USER table must have an id field wich is primary key,  and TIME table too.

Comment: @L.Fox - this is a seperate relationship, I will remove from above

Comment: Does the USER have a relationship with a RUN?

Comment: @Eric - these have all the usual primary keys, I just didn't specify them for the example

Comment: @L.Fox - not directly, no - it does not have a relationship with run. The user only has a relationship with times that have a relationship with run

Comment: do you have done a Migration code for Time Table ? if yes, in the CreateTimesTable function (in database\migration\xxxxx_create_times_table.php) you set indexes; at this point you can set a unique index based on run_id + user_id.  see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065697/schema-builder-laravel-migrations-unique-on-two-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a unique key constraint on the `times` table to enforce unique combinations of user_id and run_id

```
$table->unique(['user_id, 'run_id']);
```

To validate uniqueness at the application level, we can also add a constraint to the form validation. Assuming that you are passing both user_id and run_id in the request to create a new time, you can add the following to a form request

```
/**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => Rule::unique('times')->where('run_id', $this->input('run_id'))
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'user_id.unique' => 'A user may only have 1 time entry per Run'
        ];
    }
```

This will enforce the user_id is unique in the `times` table, filtered by that run id. The messages function also returns a more useful error message, since "user_id must be unique" is unhelpful in this situation.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I will now have to post a separate question I think :)

Comment: How would you check for this when adding rows to the database? Or is this just for database integrity and not for Laravel to handle?

Comment: Laravel's validation rules can also work with compound keys, let me try to write something up and I'll edit my answer

Comment: Okay, updated the answer with a form validation rule you can add.

Comment: However - now when I try to submit a run time, I always get the message "A user may only have 1 time entry per run" on every single user..

Comment: Here is a screencast of the issue: https://www.screencast.com/t/LwrnWjEVrI

Comment: try changing `Rule::unique('times')` to` Rule::unique('times', 'user_id')` and leaving the rest as is, I'm not sure if the rule is correctly interpreting which column actually has to be unique

Comment: Strange - same issue!

Answer (score 1):

This answer should supplement the accepted answer. You should still define the pair of user_id,run_id as a unique key. 
However, in your case user and run have an N-N relationship with `times` as a pivot table. You should code it as such.

User

```
public function runs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Run::class, 'times')->withPivot('time');;
}
```

Run:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'times')->withPivot('time');
}
```

Then you can retrieve them as:

```
$runs = User::find($userId)->runs; // Collection of all runs a user participated in
// $runs[X]->pivot->time has the time
```

You can check [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for more info

Comment: I wish I could give two answers "best answer". A combination of this and the other answer helped me achieve the overall goal. This is also how I retrieve users that do NOT have a run: $runners = User::whereDoesntHave('runs', function($q) use($run) {
            $q->where('run_id', $run->id);
        })->whereHas("roles", function($q){ // get users only of certain roles
            $q->where("name", "Student")
                ->orWhere("name", "PLT Student");
        })->get();

Comment: Just realised that maybe a pivot table isn't the best way to do this? As as soon as I want to delete a "time" it causes problems. Pivot tables don't usually have ID's and when I want to delete a "time" I cannot access it in the normal way to delete it

Comment: Yes in that case you would need to "dettach" a run from a user.