# Laravel form validation rules for checking unique using primary key and foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-validation

I know how to check unique using single id like following,

```
$addrules = array(
        'GradeName' =>  array('required','regex:/^./','unique:class,GradeName,'.$id.',AutoID'),   
                             );
```

then i want to use to check unique two id (primary and foreign key)

This is my code:

```
$update = array(
        'GradeName' =>  array('required','regex:/^./','unique:class,GradeName,'.$schoolid.',schoolid,'.$data.',AutoID'),   
                             );
```

But i have following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '20' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `class` where `GradeName` = g1 and `schoolid` <> 3 and `20` = AutoID)
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: number of array elements in upper and lower doesn't match??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990723/laravel-4-making-a-combination-of-values-columns-unique ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this error using following code

```
$update = array(
        'GradeName' =>  array('required','regex:/^./','unique:class,GradeName,'.$data.',AutoID,schoolid,'.$schoolid),   
                             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass wrong parameters, following with doc

```
unique:table,column,except,idColumn

You may also specify more conditions that will be added as "where" clauses to the query:

'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check.
```

So, you can pass foregein key in your way.

Comment: i have this error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `class` where `GradeName` = g1 and `3` <> schoolid and `20` = AutoID)"

Comment: sorry, you should also change order with second parameter. Change $data and AutoID. I edited post

Comment: i have this error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `class` where `GradeName` = g1 and `3` <> schoolid and `AutoID` = 20)"