# How to ignore uniqueness for multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I have two models: Cities and Schools. As you already understand Cities can have many schools and taking this into account I have defined my model as follows:

```
class School extends Model
{
   public $fillable = ['city_id' ,'name'];

     public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City','city_id','id');
    }

}

class City extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['name'];

    Public function schools()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\School', 'id','city_id');
    }
}
```

But I have faced a pproblem when trying to validate update of a school model. I have to validate whether name of the school is unique for selected city or not. I have defined the rule like this:

```
$rules = array(
  'name' => ['required', Rule::unique('schools')->ignore($id)],
);
$validator=Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);
```

But it is not allowing to save a school with existing name in other city than selected. How should I change the rule to ensure that school names can be same if the city is different.

Thank you.

Comment: Adding Additional Where Clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom rule

The best solution would be to create a [custom rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules) for this, that accepts the field with the corresponding city name/id as a parameter.

Something like

```
//Calling the custom rule like this
['name' => 'required|validateSchool:yourFieldNameOfCityHere'];
```

Declaring the custom validation function in your service provider like this

```
Validator::extend('validateSchool', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
   $cityName = ($validator->data, $parameters[0]);

   //Now check if the $value is already set for the specific city by using normal database queries and comparison
  return count(City::whereName($cityName)->schools()->whereName($value)->get()) == 0
});
```

---

### What does it

The custom validation rule receives the data of the field you give with the function (in the code above it's `yourFieldNameOfCityHere`), so it knows which city the user chose. With this information, you now can check if there is already a school with the name for the entered city.

Answer (score 0):

At the DB level, it sounds like what you want is a compound uniqueness constraint across name and city_id. Eloquent seems to support passing an array of column names in model definitions. It seems like this requires custom validation, though. See  [Laravel 4: making a combination of values/columns unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990723/laravel-4-making-a-combination-of-values-columns-unique) and the custom validator at https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator